# What are the advantages of @MatrixVariable over @RequestParam?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I am reading in this article http://www.kscodes.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-matrix-variable-example/ that one advantage is that you can use the variable type `Map` for the matrix variable and you can't use this type when using `@RequestParam`. But aside from that, are there any other reasons for why I should use `@MatrixVariable` instead of `@RequestParam`?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) the [`@MatrixVariable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/MatrixVariable.html) is separated by a semicolon `;` and multiple values are separated by a comma `,`. Read its documentation:

> Annotation which indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a name-value pair within a path segment. Supported for RequestMapping annotated handler methods.

There are plenty of examples and variations of the usage. Here are some exapmles:

- URL: `localhost:8080/person/Tom;age=25;height=175` and Controller:

  ```
  @GetMapping("/person/{name}")
  @ResponseBody
  public String person(
      @PathVariable("name") String name, 
      @MatrixVariable("age") int age,
      @MatrixVariable("height") int height) {

      // ...
  }
  ```
- It can be even mapped to `String[]`.

  URL: `localhost:8080/person/Tom;languages=JAVA,JAVASCRIPT,CPP,C` and Controller

  ```
  public String person(
      @PathVariable("name") String name, 
      @MatrixVariable("languages") String[] languages) {

      // ...
  }
  ```

Comment: ok so another advantage is that you can send an array as a matrixvariable value? Is that the sole advantage over @RequestParam, or are there others as well? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: also, if you don't mind. Could you give me an example of the usage? One that clearly shows its benefit as opposed to using @RequestParam

Comment: @Maurice: I have included two examples, more can be found on Google (I suggest you [ProgramCreek](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.MatrixVariable) under the key `@MatrixVariable usages example`. This annotation makes an easy mapping of multiple or variable number values separated with `,` and `;`.